# Многоточие в Си

Tags: c

Ковыряю исходники библиотеки от TI для микроконтроллеров со встроенным Bluetooth и встретил такое объявление функции:
`uint32_t icall_directAPI( uint8_t service, icall_lite_id_t id, ... );`
Получается, в Си можно объявить функцию с неизвестным заранее числом аргументов?
И как потом обращаться к этим аргументам?
Гугл ничего толкового не находит, подскажите, где можно почитать про многоточия в Си

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Вариативная_функция

Comment: В любом учебнике по C. Или [поиском в Гугле](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8+%D1%81+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%B2+C). Только сразу выбрасывайте все материалы, где работают не с `stdarg.h` и `va_list`.

Comment: Крутяк, спасибо)

Comment: Чему вы удивляетесь, неужели никогда `printf` не использовали?